# Populate array to ssh in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, ssh

Just some background, I have a file with 1000 servers in it new line delimted. I have to read them to an array the run about 5 commands over SSH. I have been using heredoc notation but that seems to fail. Currently I get an error saying the host isn't recognized.

```
    IFS='\n' read -d '' -r -a my_arr < file
    my_arr=()
    for i in "${my_arr[@]}"; do
            ssh "$1" bash -s << "EOF"
            echo "making back up of some file"
            cp /path/to/file /path/to/file.bak
            exit
    EOF
    done
```

I get output that lists the first server but then all the ones in the array as well. I know that I am missing a redirect for STDIN that causes this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is no `$i` in your script, other than as the item being iterated over. Do you want `$i` rather than `$1`?

Comment: ...to be clear, this has *nothing at all* to do with ssh, or with heredocs. You'd have the exact same problem with any other command -- `for i in "${my_arr[@]}"; do echo "$1"; done` would fail in the same way.

Comment: BTW, use `declare -p my_arr` to print its contents unambiguously, to answer the question of whether the array is in fact correctly populated.

Comment: As a second aside -- `EOF` is only honored as the end of a heredoc if not indented. If your *real* file isn't indented, the use only a four-space indent in your question to accurately reflect that, rather than the eight-space indent given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need an array? What is wrong with:

```
while read -r host
do
  ssh "$host" bash -s << "EOF"
  echo "making back up of some file"
  cp /path/to/file /path/to/file.bak
EOF
done < file
```

Comment: using the EOF in the loop causes the file to end. Since you can use anything I've changed it to END. This resolves the issue.

Comment: @zinnadean, the string `EOF` *does not* cause the file to end, unless the file itself is enclosed in a larger heredoc using that same sigil. In short, that problem can only be caused if you've got extra context not included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear -- the problem here, and *the only* problem present in the code *actually included in your question*, is that you're using `$1` inside your loop, whereas you specified `$i` as the variable that contains the entry being iterated over on each invocation of the loop.

That is to say: `ssh "$1"` needs to instead by `ssh "$i"`.

Comment: It was an error when I transcribed it. It should be "$i".

Comment: Then your original code is, in and of itself, fine -- and your bug is something that only takes place in the context of code you didn't provide in the question.